# unresolved external symbol - calling static function from other project

Tags: c++

I have solution with two projects- `proj_1`, `proj_2`.

`proj_1` is lib project and `proj_2` is regular project

in `proj_2` I have function named `static void proj_2_func()`.
Im trying to call that function from `proj_1` (without creating an object) but I get linkage error- `unresolved external symbol`.

```
proj_2:

class proj_2_class
{
  public:
   static void proj_2_func();  //the implementation is not relevant
}


proj_1:

in cpp file:

#include proj_2_class.h  // I added the path to "additional include files" in proj_1

void proj_1_class::proj_1_func()
{
  proj_2_class::proj_2_func();
}
```

Ill be happy for guidance on that error.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function `proj_1_class::proj_1_func` calls the function `proj_2_class::proj_2_func`, the latter needs to have an implementation provided somewhere - failing to do so is what causes the linker error

Comment: it has implementation on `proj_2` class..

Comment: Is the file `proj_2.cpp` (or whatever the file is called which provides said implementation) compiled when building `proj_1`? I suspect not

Comment: I first compiled `proj_2` and after that- compiled `proj_1`

Comment: Then you're not including the object file produced by `proj_2` during linking. Can you share your linker command line, and also the full linker error (i.e. which exact symbol is it complaining about)?

Comment: I dont have linking to `proj_2` from `proj_1`because its not dll project (probably this is my error). the only outputs `.pdb` file. how should the linker look like?

Comment: this is the full linker error:  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public:static void _cdecl proj_2::proj_2_func()" referenced in function "public: void _cdecl proj_1::proj_1_func()"

Comment: Then you need to add `proj_2` as a library used in building `proj_1`. If you were doing this directly on the command line, you would add the option `-lproj_2` at the end of your command line, assuming `proj_2` is built into `proj_2.dll`.

Comment: Im working on visual studio... I wrote it on the question- `proj_2` is not dll project, its regular project.. should I recompile it as dll project? it has `main` ...

Comment: If `proj_2` is not a library, then how can you 'use' it from `proj_1`? Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't make any sense. If you want say an executable to use code from somewhere else, that 'somewhere else' is either a library (most common case) or manually added object files. You can certainly manually add object files from `proj_2` to `proj_1` using the command line, but if you need to do that then probably you're muddled about what exactly you're trying to do. It would be better to just have `proj_2` be a library instead, or else merge it into `proj_1` so that they're one project